# SAS 9.4 playing up with IFN function results

Tags: sas

I recently moved to SAS 9.4, and found a weird bug with IFN and IFC fucntion. Please see the code below illustarting IFN fucntion:

```
data a;
input b 8.;
datalines;
0.1
150
110
9.1
1
0

;
run;

proc sql;
create table test as 
select b, (IFN(b = .  | b  > 100 | b  < 1 ,1,0)) as f_no_overlap length = 8,
(IFN(b in (.,0) | b > 100 | b  < 1 ,1,0)) as m_overlap length = 8,
(IFN(b in (.,0) | b  < 1 ,1,0)) as u_no_100,
(IFN(b in (0,110) | b  < 1 | b > 100 ,1,0)) as b_no_null,
(IFN(b = 0 | b  < 1 | b > 100 | b= . ,1,0)) as h_last_miss, 
(IFN(b = . | b = 0 | b  < 1 | b > 100,1,0)) as k_first_null,
(IFN(b = 0 | b = . | b  < 1 | b > 100,1,0)) as y_second_null,
(IFN(b = 0 | b  < 1 | b = . | b > 100,1,0)) as l_third_null,
(IFN(b  < 1 | b = 0 | b = . | b > 100,1,0)) as o_first_one from a;
quit;
```

I get the following results :
[image]

Where as the same code on SAS 9.3 gives the following results (which is correct) :
[image]

Why does it behave so weird with the same conditions on 9.4, mainly it seems to be the NULL in condition that seems to be causing an issue.
Has anyone encountered the same problem? Do we have a solution for it?

Comment: If by "NULL" you mean "missing" then try checking what your missing value is set to (it might not be '.'). Try running `proc options option = missing; run;` and check the value displayed in the log.

Comment: Since there is nothing particular in that code that requires SQL try rewriting it as a data step and running in both versions of SAS.  Also why are you using IFN() to generate boolean answers?  You can replace `ifn(condition,1,0)` with just `condition` and SAS will still generate 1 for true and 0 for false..

Comment: What version of SAS are you running?  I cannot reproduce errors with `sysvlong=
9.04.01M5P091317`.

Comment: @Tom - I'm on SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4 TS1M4 . Can you tell me what version are you on since you mentioned you don't see these erroneous results?

Comment: I posted it already. 9.4M5.

Answer (score 3):

The discussion of unexpected evaluation results is for code run in SAS 9.4 TS1M4 on Windows 10.0.17763 Build 17763.

```
3    proc options;
4    run;

    SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4  TS1M4
```

SQL does not have a missing value (`.`, `.<letter>`) concept in the same way DATA Step and other Procs do.  SQL has NULL and SAS coerces missing values into NULL, so there is a fuzzy edge and you found a problem there !

The failure to properly evaluate an expression appears to be how 9.4 SQL implementation is processing literal missing (`.`) values in this specific case.  The failure is not in the `IFN`, but rather the evaluation passed to `IFN` !

Examining only the logic expression the problems does not seem to be related to `IN`.  Similar unexpected evaluation results occur when the `IN` is split into a series of `OR`s.  The specific causation appears to be where the missing literal (`.`) appears in the expression -- which in turn becomes 9.4 SQL implementation innards (parsing, etc.)

Definitely seems to be a bug when more than two sub-expressions and one of them uses a missing (`.`).  The proper remedy, and one that becomes more suitable for remote or pass-through processing, would be to avoid using missing literals (`.`) in your SQL and use ANSI null tests operators `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`

```
data have;
  b = 9.1;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
  b
  , b in (.,0) | b > 100                      as part1                        /* correct result */
  , b in (.,0)           | b < 1              as part2                        /* correct result */
  ,              b > 100 | b < 1              as part3                        /* correct result */
  , b in (.,0) | b > 100 | b < 1              as parts_null_first             /* INCORRECT result */
  ,              b > 100 | b < 1 | b in (.,0) as parts_null_last              /* INCORRECT result */
  , b=. | b=0  | b > 100 | b < 1              as parts_no_in_null_first       /* INCORRECT result */
  ,       b=0  | b > 100 | b < 1 | b= .       as parts_no_in_null_last        /* correct - weird? */

  , b is null | b=0 | b > 100 | b < 1 as parts_is_null                        /* correct result */

  , calculated part1 | calculated part2 | calculated part3 as calc_parts_in_1_expr /* correct result */

  from have
  ;
quit;
```

I didn't test if the same issue occurs when the problematic expression is in a `WHERE` caluse.  The expression is not a problem as an assignment in DATA step:

```
data want2;
  set have;
  parts_null_first = b in (.,0) | b > 100 | b < 1 ;                 /* correct result  */
  parts_null_last  =              b > 100 | b < 1 | b in (.,0);     /* correct result */
run;
```

If the expression evaluation 'error' occurs in where expressions, then the where evaluation engine is more likely the root cause -- I believe the same engine is used for Proc/Data WHERE statements, Dataset WHERE= option and SQL evaluations.

There might be a SAS Note or Hotfix for the situation but I didn't go looking.

Another discussion of testing for missing values can be found in SAS_Tipster's ["SAS Tip: Use IS MISSING and IS NULL with Numeric or Character Variables"](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Tips-from-the-Community/SAS-Tip-Use-IS-MISSING-and-IS-NULL-with-Numeric-or-Character/td-p/475183) on communities.sas.com.  The important take away is the use of operators in criteria testing for null values.

> The IS MISSING and IS NULL operators, which are used with a WHERE statement, can handle character or numeric variables. They also work with the NOT operator:

[Documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/fedsqlref/67364/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1dyxnpnux73htn1ib6vzfrcp8yb.htm) summarizes `IS MISSING predicate` as:

> Tests for a SAS missing value in a SAS native data store.

Comment: Ugh, that's a bad bug.

Comment: What version of SAS are you running?  I don't see any problems when running your code.

Comment: `3    proc options;
4    run;

    SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4  TS1M4`

Comment: @Tom- this is the SAS version that I'm using : SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4  TS1M4
and proc options option = missing; gives me this :
 MISSING=.         Specifies the character to print for missing numeric values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Richard. I wonder how come nulls work well here:`proc sql;
create table test1 as
select b
from a
where (b = .  | b  > 100 | b  < 1 );
quit;` for the same dataset a, I have multiple OR conditions in my where clause and one being NULL, it gives the following results :                                          
`b
0.1
150
110
0`
which are correct, not sure how '.' works well here and not in the IFN condition specified above.

Answer (score 0):

SAS came back wi this response :
We have now released Problem Note XXXXXX: Problem with the IFN function in SAS 9.4TS1M4 in regard to this issue. It seems only circumvention at this stage is upgrade to a newer version of SAS such as SAS 9.4M5 (TS1M5) or later. so, no hotfix or solution available at this stage for this problem in the current version.